# Probability from Logit Regression

Tags: regression, probability, logit

I am trying to predict a sale using a logit regression. My dependent variable is `isSale` and my dependent variables include only binary variables such as `isHighSale_City`, `isHighSale_Domain`, etc.

I have my regression output and converted the coefficients to odds and then to probability.

> predicted_probability = odds_ratio / (1 + odds_ratio)

My question is *can I sum the probabilities that I generated from the odds ratio to create a combined probability for the observation?*

Example:

> isHighSale_City: coef: 1.19; odds_ratio: 3.52; pred_probability: 0.779
>
> isHighSale_Domain: coef: 0.61; odds_ratio: 1.83; pred_probability: 0.65
>
> Intercept: coef: -6.88; odds_ratio: 0.00057; pred_probability: 0.00057

If I want to score an prospective sale in  a high sale city and high sale domain, would it be:

> 0.779 + 0.65 + 0.00057 = 1.429

Comment: Could you explain how you would interpret a "probability" of $1.429$?

Comment: For an observation where isHighSale_City=1 and isHighSale_Domain=1, the probability of it converting to a sale is 142% higher than if it isn't in a high sale city and a high sale domain?

Comment: @jonjon that is a probability *ratio* not a probability. The numbers should conform to the interpretation, not *vice versa*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is incorrect. *Odds* can be converted to probability using the equation above. However, *odds ratios* are ratios of two different odds representing distinct probabilities. The model estimates from a logistic regression are additive on the *log-odds scale*. Create predictions on this scale using the appropriate coefficients, then transform the linear predictor using the inverse logit: $$\text{expit}(\alpha + x\beta) = (1+\exp(\alpha +x\beta))^{-1}$$.

This is the probabilistic prediction equation from a logistic regression. The intercept $\alpha$ is the log odds for response when all covariates are 0. The slope $\beta$ is the *log* odds ratio for adjacent groups in discrete or continuous $x$.

Comment: Ah, so i can create an additive probability and then take the inverse logit to get a more "readable" probability for the observation?

Comment: I don't understand what a readable probability is. The probability is not added. The inverse logit of a probability is a log-odds. Using logistic regression parameters, you can add up the log odds (intercept) and *log* odds ratios in the fashion you've shown, then reverse transform them (with inverse logit) to obtain a probability. Or fit an additive risk model.

Comment: Apologies if I'm not completely clear. I'm relatively new to this.

Comment: The resources I'm finding online mostly stop at an explanation of the odds ratio. I'm trying to create a probabilistic score.                                                      To find the probability of a sale, I can take: **a + (x)HighSale_city + (x)HighSale_domain**, then take the inverse logit to find the probability?

Comment: @jonjon yes! the value you use there is the one entitled "coef" and not "odds ratio".